# Forcing labels on histograms in each individual graph in a figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my code thus far:
[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
for position, col in enumerate(cols):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3,3,position+1)
    ax.hist(with_diabetes[col], histtype ='step', label='With Diabetes')
    ax.hist(without_diabetes[col], histtype ='step', label = 'No Diabetes')
    plt.title(col)

plt.show()
```

I want the labels clearly showing in each graph so there's never a question which is which.

I tried adding the `label` parameter, but while the graphs appear perfectly, I can't make the labels appear. They don't show in any of the graphs generated by my code.

I also tried adding the `legend=True` argument but that just caused the code not to be able to run.

Comment: If I'm understanding correct, have you tried adding "ax.legend()" inside the for-loop?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. How do I mark a comment as a solution?? xD

Comment: No problem, I have to post it as an "Answer" then you mark that. I'll do that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `ax.legend()` inside your for-loop.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))

for position, col in enumerate(cols):
   ax = fig.add_subplot(3,3,position+1)
   ax.hist(with_diabetes[col], histtype ='step', label='With Diabetes')
   ax.hist(without_diabetes[col], histtype ='step', label = 'No Diabetes')
   ax.legend()
   plt.title(col)
plt.show()
```